# Pyspark SQL Pandas Grouped Map without GroupBy?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset that I want to map over using several Pyspark SQL [Grouped Map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#grouped-map) UDFs, at different stages of a larger ETL process that runs on ephemeral clusters in AWS EMR. The Grouped Map API requires that the Pyspark dataframe be grouped prior to the apply, but I have no need to actually group keys.

At the moment, I'm using an arbitrary grouping, which works, but results in:

1. An unnecessary shuffle.
2. Hacky code for an arbitrary groupby in each job.

My ideal solution allows a vectorized Pandas UDF apply without an arbitrary grouping, but if I could save the arbitrary grouping that would at least eliminate the shuffles.

**EDIT**:

Here's what my code looks like. I was originally using an arbitrary grouping, but am currently trying `spark_partition_id()` based on a comment below by @pault.

```py
@pandas_udf(b_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def transform(a_partition):
  b = a_partition.drop("pid", axis=1)
  # Some other transform stuff
  return b

(sql
  .read.parquet(a_path)
  .withColumn("pid", spark_partition_id())
  .groupBy("pid")
  .apply(transform)
  .write.parquet(b_path))
```

Using `spark_partition_id()` seems to still result in a shuffle. I get the following DAG:

#### Stage 1

1. Scan parquet
2. Project
3. Project
4. Exchange

#### Stage 2

1. Exchange
2. Sort
3. FlatMapGroupsInPandas

Comment: Please share the code of grouping. What you tried? what exactly failing?

Comment: @pault using the partition ID seems to still result in a shuffle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To support roughly equivalent logic (functions `(pandas.core.frame.DataFrame) -> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`) you'll have to switch to Spark 3.0.0 and use `MAP_ITER` transformation.

In the latest preview version (3.0.0-preview2) you'll need an UDF:

```py
@pandas_udf(b_schema, PandasUDFType.MAP_ITER)
def transform(dfs):
    for df in dfs:
        b = df.drop("pid", axis=1)
        ...
        yield b

df.mapInPandas(transform)
```

and in the upcoming 3.0.0 release ([SPARK-28264](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-28264)) just a plain function:

```py
def transform(dfs):
    for df in dfs:
        b = df.drop("pid", axis=1)
        # Some other transform stuff
        ...
        yield b

df.mapInPandas(transform, b_schema)
```

A possible workaround on 2.x would be to use plain `SCALAR` UDF, serialize each row of the result as JSON, and deserialize it on the other side, i.e.

```py
import json
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json

@pandas_udf("string", PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def transform(col1, col2):
    b = pd.DataFrame({"x": col1, "y": col2})
    ...
    return b.apply(lambda x: json.dumps(dict(zip(df.columns, x))), axis=1)


(df
    .withColumn("json_result", transform("col1", "col2"))
    .withColumn("a_struct", from_json("json_result", b_schema)))
```